# How to add another video to MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, media-player

Is it possible to make a playlist for MPMoviePlayer? all videos are from internet.
While player runs, when it comes to 1 minute position i want to play another video from URL.
second video is an ads clip. after ads clip finishes, main video should continue.
is it possible? i saw some ipad apps, like hulu plus.

what steps should i make?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the playbackdidfinish notification:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And make your player fetch the next item in your playlist with this method

```
    -(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;
```

You can save the url's in a plist file and keep track of the current item beign played using a simple integer index.